# Solve PDE $2(u_x^2+u_y^2)^{\frac{1}{2}} - (u_z^2+u_w^2)^{\frac{1}{2}} = 1$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Solve PDE
$$2(u_x^2+u_y^2)^{\frac{1}{2}} - (u_z^2+u_w^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}  = 1$$
for $u(x,y,z,w)$ with boundary condition
$$
u(D)=0
$$
where
$$
D=\left\{(a,b,a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^4 \mid a,b\in\mathbb{R}\right\}.
$$
I was able to discover a solution:
$$
u(x,y,z,w)=\sqrt{(x-z)^2+(y-w)^2}
$$
However, I am struggling to determine the general solution. I try to apply a change of variables method but haven't had any success.

My next goal is to solve
$$2\|\nabla_{\mathbf{x}}u\| - \|\nabla_{\mathbf{y}}u\| - \|\nabla_{\mathbf{z}}u\|  = 1$$ for  $u(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y},\mathbf{z})=u(x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2,z_1,z_2)$, which seems much harder than this question.

I am new to PDE and would appreciate any corrections or guidance if my inquiries reveal misconceptions or inaccuracies.

Comment: You can use the fact that that the equation remains invariant under dilations of the form $u(x, y, w, z) \to \lambda^{-1} u(\lambda x, \lambda y, \lambda w, \lambda z), \lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ to show that $u$ is a homogeneous function of degree one from which you can use [Euler's homogeneous function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_function#Euler's_theorem)